# Create an empty list before the loop in Python

Tags: python, list

I always have a question about the empty list before the for the loop. For example, why do we need to create an empty list `value = []` before `for token in user_input.split()`?
When do we need to create such an empty list? Thanks so much for your help.

```
def get_numbers():
    user_input = input()
    values = []
    for token in user_input.split():
        values.append(int(token))
    return values

def print_selected_numbers():
    numbers = get_numbers()
    for number in numbers:
        if number > 9:
            print(number)

print_selected_numbers()
```

Comment: If we didn't have an empty list (named `values` here), what would we append to?

Comment: You have to make an object exist first before you can use a method of that object. Doing `values = []` says to Python "I declare that a new object named `values` exists and that it's of type `list`". Now python knows that `values` has a method named `append()` because it's a list object. In most other programming languages you have to formally declare a variable of a particular type. `Declare values as List` (psuedocode). Python is much less picky, it just wants you to give it a hint like `values = []` and it will figure it out from there.

Comment: (In this case a list comprehension would be more idiomatic, but when building a list in a loop like this we need a container to put the elements into.)

Comment: "I declare that a new object named `values` exists and that it's of type `list`"—well, not exactly. Python doesn't have type declarations. This creates an empty list via the literal `[]` and binds that object to the name `values`. It doesn't declare that `values` is of type `list`.

Comment: @Chris I added to my comment as you were writing that, I think we are saying the same thing.

Comment: @JNevill, I'm not so sure. `values = []` has nothing to do with typing, it's required because we need a container. Type systems are a distraction here.

Comment: @Chris I think it does matter in that the `.append()` method is not a method of a generic container, but rather to particular types of containers like tuples and lists (not dictionaries). I'm still pretty new to python, so I may be way off base here.

Comment: @JNevill, you need to know what kind of object `values` refers to when you interact with it, sure. But that has nothing to do with why `values = []` appears before the loop. That is what OP is asking: "why do we need to create an empty list `value = []` before `for token in user_input.split()`?". The reason `values = []` is needed has _nothing at all_ to do with type systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris and JNevill noted in the comments to your answer, we need a container that defines an `.append` method. The empty list is such a container.

As noted by Chris, you can use list comprehension as such:

```
def get_numbers():
    return [int(token) for token in input().split()]
```